# How Can I Flash Coral Dev Board Mini on Windows?

Tags: linux, google-coral, debian-based, mendel-os

I want to use latest Mendel OS for coral dev board mini. I checked the coral website but they didn't provide any way for windows (Just Linux and Macs). Do someone know how can I do this on windows? I tried with wls but it does not (Couldn't find device)

I tried first method for linux (Windows Linux System) but it does not work. I want to flash my board to new Mendel OS

Answer (score 0):

I sucessfully found my Device in Ubunutu Subsystems on Windows 11 using WSL2.
Follow the steps of the following link to get it done.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/connecting-usb-devices-to-wsl/